# Linking to Fortran libraries from C fails

Tags: c, configuration, fortran, mpi

I am trying to install [score-p](http://www.vi-hps.org/projects/score-p) to profile MPI programs. I followed the instructions in INSTALL file. The steps I did so far:

```
mkdir _build
cd _build
../configure
```

the last command gave the following error:

```
configure: error: linking to Fortran libraries from C fails
See `config.log' for more details
configure: error: ../../build-mpi/configure failed for build-mpi
```

Related lines in config.log are as follows:

```
configure:8044: running /bin/bash ../../build-mpi/configure --disable-option-checking 'FCLIBS= ' 'SHMEMFC=oshfort' 'SHMEM_LIB_NAME=oshmem' 'FC=gfortran' 'SHMEMCC=oshcc' 'SHMEMF77=oshfort' 'F77=gfortran' 'MPIF77=mpif77' 'SHMEMCXX=oshcc' 'CC=gcc' 'CXX=g++' 'MPICXX=mpicxx' 'MPIFC=mpif90' 'SHMEM_NAME=OpenSHMEM' 'MPICC=mpicc' 'ac_scorep_platform=linux' 'ac_scorep_cross_compiling=no' 'afs_scorep_platform_name=Linux' 'afs_scorep_default_machine_name=Linux' --cache-file=/dev/null --srcdir=../../build-mpi
configure:8049: error: ../../build-mpi/configure failed for build-mpi
```

It makes me think that the problem is MPI related since the error message mentiones `build-mpi`. Related posts suggest adding `FCLIBS=" "` after `../configure` but this did not help. What I am doing wrong?

**Edit:** After Zulan's and Vladimir F's comments I checked out `/build-mpi/config.log`. Here is the error statement: `/usr/bin/gold: error: cannot find -lmpi_mpifh` with the following code right after this statement.

```
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "Score-P"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "scorep"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "3.0"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "Score-P 3.0"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "support@score-p.org"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define AFS_PACKAGE_BUILD "MPI backend"
| #define AFS_PACKAGE_SRCDIR "../../build-mpi/../"
| #define AFS_PACKAGE_BUILD_name mpi_backend
| #define AFS_PACKAGE_BUILD_NAME MPI_BACKEND
| #define AFS_PACKAGE_name scorep
| #define AFS_PACKAGE_NAME SCOREP
| #define PACKAGE "scorep"
| #define VERSION "3.0"
| #define STDC_HEADERS 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRING_H 1
| #define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
| #define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
| #define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
| #define HAVE_DLFCN_H 1
| #define LT_OBJDIR ".libs/"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #define F77_DUMMY_MAIN _MAIN
| #ifdef F77_DUMMY_MAIN
|
| #  ifdef __cplusplus
|      extern "C"
| #  endif
|    int F77_DUMMY_MAIN() { return 1; }
|
| #endif
| int
| main ()
| {
|
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
```

**Edit 2:** `locate libmpi_mpifh` yields

```
/usr/lib/libmpi_mpifh.so.12
/usr/lib/libmpi_mpifh.so.12.0.0
/usr/lib/openmpi/lib/libmpi_mpifh.so.12.0.0
```

**Solved:** Symbolic linking solved the problem with `libmpi_mpifh`.

Comment: Is gfortran installed?  You can check `../configure --help` for flags you can give to `configure`.

Comment: @Davislor Yes, gfortran is installed.

Comment: Does `../configure --help` have an option like `--with-fortran=...`?

Comment: The error is probably hidden in `./build-mpi/config.log` due to the recursive configure of Score-P.

Comment: @Davislor No, there is nothing similar to `--with-fortran`.

Comment: @VladimirF Yes I did see config.log. In fact, I referred to some lines in that file.

Comment: Again, the `config.log` that this error refers to is `./build-mpi/config.log`, **not**, `./config.log`.

Comment: @Zulan Please see the edited question.